# getElementsByClassName doesn't work properly at Element nodes

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getElementsByClassName returns [] instead of asynchronous appended node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615162/getelementsbyclassname-returns-instead-of-asynchronous-appended-node)

I face the following problem:

```
<div class="testA" id="test1">
    <div class="colorSelector" id="0-0">
        <div class="gbSelector" id="1-0">
            <table style="none" id="2-0"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above written Tree is predefined. I now load a node tree via ***XMLHttpRequest*** & Co. that I append into the `<div class="testA" id="test1">`
When I now try to get the Element `<div class="colorSelector" id="0-0">` using ***getElementById("0-0")*** I get the expected result. But using ***getElementsByClassName("colorSelector")*** returns ***[]***.

Did I miss something? Is it probably a leftover of the fact the nodes were of type ***Element*** and not ***HTMLElement***?

I don't get it.

EDIT: I used the comments to visualize that the nodes are added later when processing the response

EDIT 2: http://lls-test.de/JS-Library/index.php is what I receive as a response and handle in a script to append the first DIV inside the response tag